# Copy dynamic field value to another field

Tags: javascript

I am running a database app (sql backend). One particular form calls a value from another table using the follwing:

```
<td class=NewSalesOpCompany id="contactPostCode"><#externalfield SQL="Select POSTALCODE from wce_sales s join wce_linkto l on s.UNIQUEID = l.luniqueid left join wce_contact c on l.LEntityID = c.UNIQUEID where (s.UNIQUEID = '<#field field=uniqueid  noedit static>')" ></td>
```

The above code populates the field with post-code data in text format which works fine. I then want to copy the data in that field to another field. I have tried the folwing but failed to get it to work.

```
    <script language=javascript>

function copyPostCode() {
    var parentPOSTALCODE=document.getElementById('contactPostCode');
    var oppPOSTCODE=document.forms[0]._POSTCODE;
    if (oppPOSTCODE != parentPOSTALCODE)
        { oppPOSTCODE.value = parentPOSTALCODE.value;}

        }
    </script>
```

When executing the function I get "parentPOSTALCODE.value is undefined" error via firefox. I'm a bit of a newbie at this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `oppPOSTCODE.innerText = parentPOSTALCODE.innerText;` instead of `oppPOSTCODE.value = parentPOSTALCODE.value;`

Comment: I now get "parentPOSTALCODE.innerText is undefined" error

Comment: ok `oppPOSTCOD`E is a `td` as well or is it a `<input type="text" ...`?

Comment: this is the POSTCODE field <td><#input field=POSTCODE class=NewSalesOpCreationDate></td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script language=javascript>

    function copyPostCode() {
        var parentPOSTALCODE=document.getElementById('contactPostCode');
        var oppPOSTCODE=document.forms[0]._postcode;
        if (oppPOSTCODE != parentPOSTALCODE)
        { 
           oppPOSTCODE.value = parentPOSTALCODE.innerText;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the example ***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wH6Dq/)***

Comment: same error "parentPOSTALCODE.innerText is undefined"

Comment: Can you show me the generated html of those fields, please?

Comment: Do you mean like this? <td id="contactPostCode" class="NewSalesOpCompany">TN22 1QQ</td> <input id="_postcode" class="NewSalesOpCreationDate" format="Text" value="123" name="_postcode">

Comment: @labman it is `_postcode` not `_POSTCODE`. I have changed the answer it will work now. Here is the example ***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wH6Dq/)***

Comment: oh dear, such a rookie mistake. However, that has moved it on a step. I'm not getting script errors but the destination field (_postcode) is getting updated with "undefined". I guess it's not picking up the data in oppPOSTCODE.

Comment: If the td is like `<td id="contactPostCode" class="NewSalesOpCompany">TN22 1QQ</td>` as you mentioned earlier then it should not be undefined but try using `parentPOSTALCODE.innerHTML` instead of `parentPOSTALCODE.innerText`

Comment: Brilliant, brilliant, brilliant! you're a star. Can't thank you enough.